# how to get single row in plpgsql?

Tags: postgresql

I'm querying to see if there is an end time if there isn't then I want to update it to include the current time. However, I need to store if the end time exists and the id of the row to update later on with, but I'm not quite sure how to go about doing this.

```
endTime := now();
strresult := 'select end_time from process order by start_time desc limit 1';
IF strresult = '' THEN
    UPDATE tasks SET end_time = endTime WHERE id = ???;
END IF;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking on [SELECT INTO](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/plpgsql-statements.html) statement. But you don't need it. You should not to save a current time to variable - inside transaction the time is not moving. Your code is little bit messy - you are searching a situation without opened process, then you close a tasks.

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT *
                 FROM process
                 WHERE end_time IS NULL)
THEN
   UPDATE tasks SET end_time = CURRENT_TIME
     WHERE end_time IS NULL;
END IF;
```

Comment: im searching for last process, and checking to see if end time is null or not rather then searching for process where end_time is null